# Add a column with the name "default"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

I would like to add a database table column with the name "default", is that allowed or is it a reserved word in Ruby, Rails, sqlite, postgresql...?

Comment: Not yet, I prefer to know the answer before trying it

Comment: use is_default instead ... or something similar ...

Comment: @andrea, that's a great suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of reserved words that don't play friendly as table columns in Rails
http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords

If you're using mysql, DEFAULT is a reserved word according to:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3):

"Default" is a reserved word in lots of places, including every dbms that I've used over the course of 25+ years.

There are well-known ways to use reserved words as column names, and I'm not going to tell you what they are. Why? Because I respect maintenance programmers. When they see your code, the first question they'll ask is "default @#$$%^@ what?" And they'll have to track down what it means to have a fighting chance of making a change without introducing a bug.

Be kind to your maintenance programmers, and be more descriptive. I'm pretty sure every dbms currently under wide use allows more than 8 characters in a column name.

Answer (score 1):

DEFAULT is definitely a reserved word in SQL. It might work in your DBMS and for the particularly queries you use in your app, it might not, but it will likely come back and bite you in the ass at some point.
I would refrain from using it.